# Creating Database in Android and Data Insertion

Tags: android, sqlite

I was writing a simple program for Creating Database and Data Insertion,but I'm not able to Create the Database and I am getting the "Error" from Catch Block.Even I am not able to search for my database in file explorer,but it's not showing there.As,I am new to Android,may be some mistake has happened.Please look into code and let me know where I missed.Thanks in advance.

Code is as:

Layout File:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.dataandroid.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/labelOne"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/labelTwo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.dataandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText name,age;
Button submit,save;
myDBHelper dbHelper;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);
    dbHelper=new myDBHelper(this);

    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String n= name.getText().toString();
            String a= age.getText().toString();

             try
                {
                    dbHelper.insertContact(n,a);
                }
             catch(Exception e)
             {

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
             }
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
 }

}
```

DatabaseHelperClass:

```
 package com.example.dataandroid;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class myDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final String DB_Name="mydb"; 
private static final int version=1;

private static final String table_name="Details";
private static final String Col_Name="Name";
private static final String COL_Age="Age";

//private static final  String String_Create="Create Table" + table_name + "(_id 
  Integer Primary Key AUTO INCREMENT," + Col_Name + "TEXT , " +  COL_Age + "TEXT);";
public myDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_Name, null, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String String_Create="Create Table" + table_name + "(_id Integer Primary Key AUTO 
    INCREMENT," + Col_Name + "TEXT , " +  COL_Age + "TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(String_Create);
/*  ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Col_Name," Name");
    cv.put(COL_Age, "Age");
    db.insert(table_name, null,cv);*/
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("Drop Table if exists" + table_name);
    onCreate(db);

}
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public long insertContact(String name,String age)
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(Col_Name,name);
    cv.put(COL_Age,age);
    return db.insert(table_name, null,cv);  
}

}
```

Comment: Consider logging your exceptions to learn what's wrong with the code.

Comment: HI,I checked the Logs.it's a null pointer exception.That's what I think database is not getting created.Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

you need first to open your dataBase before inserting any rows 
like this

```
dbHelper.db.open()
dbHelper.insertContact(n,a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said " I am not able to search for my database in file explorer, it is not showing there". That is because the database is saved in /data/data/your_package_name/databases/ and only if you root your phone you'll be able to see it with file explorer.
Having said that, if you still want to see your DB (say, to debug and see that is recorded in it) without rooting your phone, you can add a method in your DBConnector class to COPY the DB from its hidden location to the SD card and then you'll be able to work on it (like copy to your computer and open it with a SQLite Studio.

here is the code:

```
    public void copyDBtoSdCard() {
    File dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File inFile = mCtx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        try {
            InputStream myInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile));            
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(dataPath + "/"+ DATABASE_NAME+".db");

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[myInput.available()];
            int read;
            while ((read = myInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "copyDataBase Error : " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: HI ,thanks but forgot to mention i am using the emulator,not the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the log but still from your code it is visible that the exception is coming at the point where you are trying to insert something into the database **db.insert(table_name, null,cv);**.

You are getting null pointer exception cause your SQLiteDatabase db variable is not initialized. You need to get an instance of the database(in the case of insertion you need to get a writable database).

So you need to write this line in your insertContact method before you insert:

```
try {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    // rest of your code
} catch(SQLiteException e) {
    //log the exception
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. If your problem is solved then u can mark it as the answer and close the question.